# ScrollView not scrolling smooth with inside 3 recyclerviews

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollview

Here is my code.i want to put 3 recyclerViews in my layout but it is very slow on device while running. If there is 2 `recyclerview` it works smooth but if 3 slow very :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context=".fragments.MainFragment">





       <LinearLayout
           android:orientation="vertical"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">



           <TextView
               android:textColor="@color/blacker"
               android:textStyle="bold"
               android:textSize="18sp"
               android:text="Техника для офиса"
               android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
               android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginStart="15dp" />



           <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
               android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
               android:fillViewport="true"
               android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
               android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
               android:id="@+id/recyclerView_popular_goods"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"/>



           <TextView
               android:textColor="@color/blacker"
               android:textStyle="bold"
               android:textSize="18sp"
               android:text="Компьютерная техника"
               android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
               android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginStart="15dp" />



           <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
               android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
               android:fillViewport="true"
               android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
               android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
               android:id="@+id/recyclerView_competitive_goods"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"/>



           <TextView
               android:textColor="@color/blacker"
               android:textStyle="bold"
               android:textSize="18sp"
               android:text="Канцелярские товары"
               android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
               android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginStart="15dp" />



           <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
               android:visibility="gone"
               android:fillViewport="true"
               android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
               android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
               android:id="@+id/recyclerView_stationery_goods"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

       </LinearLayout>
```

Please if somebody had such kind of problem please help me to fix my issue.

I tried `Nested scrollview` and  `setNestedScrollingEnabled = false`.but nothing helps

Here is my Activity

```
   @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
   public class MainFragment extends BasicFragment implements 
   MainFragmentView, PopularGoodsAdapter.ProductListener {


  @BindView(R.id.scroll_view)
  NestedScrollView mScrollView;



@BindView(R.id.recyclerView_stationery_goods)
RecyclerView mRecyclerViewStationeryGoods;


@BindView(R.id.recyclerView_popular_goods)
RecyclerView mRecyclerViewPopularGoods;


@BindView(R.id.recyclerView_competitive_goods)
RecyclerView mRecyclerViewCompetitiveGoods;


@BindView(R.id.imageSlider)
SliderView mSliderView;


@Inject
Navigator mNavigator;


@Inject
@Named(DISPLAY_WIDTH)
int mDisplayWidth;


@InjectPresenter
MainFragmentPresenter mPresenter;


List<Product> list1;
List<Product> list2;
List<Product> list3;


private PopularGoodsAdapter mAdapterPopularGoods;
private PopularGoodsAdapter mAdapterPopularGoods2;
private PopularGoodsAdapter mAdapterPopularGoods3;
private LayoutAnimationController layoutAnimationController;
private List<String> images;


@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public MainFragment() {

}





private void initView(View view) {
    ButterKnife.bind(this,view);

    images = new LinkedList<>();
    images.add("https://images.pexels.com/photos/747964/pexels-photo-747964.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260");
    images.add("https://images.pexels.com/photos/929778/pexels-photo-929778.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260");
    images.add("https://images.pexels.com/photos/218983/pexels-photo-218983.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260");

    mSliderView.setSliderAdapter(new SliderAdapterExample(getContext(), images, "mainPage"));


    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager2 = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager3 = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

    mRecyclerViewPopularGoods.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    layoutAnimationController = AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(getContext(),R.anim.layout_item_from_left);


    list1 = new LinkedList<>();
    mRecyclerViewPopularGoods.setLayoutAnimation(layoutAnimationController);



    mRecyclerViewCompetitiveGoods.setLayoutManager(layoutManager2);

    list2 = new LinkedList<>();
    mRecyclerViewCompetitiveGoods.setLayoutAnimation(layoutAnimationController);



    mRecyclerViewStationeryGoods.setLayoutManager(layoutManager3);

    list3 = new LinkedList<>();
    mRecyclerViewStationeryGoods.setLayoutAnimation(layoutAnimationController);



    mRecyclerViewPopularGoods.setAdapter(mAdapterPopularGoods = new PopularGoodsAdapter(getContext(),list1,mDisplayWidth,"popular",this));
    mRecyclerViewCompetitiveGoods.setAdapter(mAdapterPopularGoods2 = new PopularGoodsAdapter(getContext(),list2,mDisplayWidth,"competitive",this));
    mRecyclerViewStationeryGoods.setAdapter(mAdapterPopularGoods3 = new PopularGoodsAdapter(getContext(),list3,mDisplayWidth,"stationery",this));

    mRecyclerViewPopularGoods.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    mRecyclerViewCompetitiveGoods.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    mRecyclerViewStationeryGoods.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);


    getLoadingDialog().showDialog(getFragmentManager());
    mPresenter.GET_TOP_HOME_VIEW();

}




@Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup 
   container, 
  Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, 
     false);
    initView(view);
    return view;
  }










@OnClick({R.id.item_sellers,
 R.id.item_price_request,R.id.item_price_competitions})
  void Onclick(View view) {
      switch (view.getId()) {

        case R.id.item_sellers:

                mNavigator.toSellersActivty(getContext());

            break;

        case R.id.item_price_request:

                mNavigator.toPriceRequestActivty(getContext());

            break;

        case R.id.item_price_competitions:

                mNavigator.toCompetitionsActivty(getContext());

            break;

    }
}




@Override
public void initTopHomeView(List<HomeViewObject> result) {

    if (null != result ) {

        if (result.size() >= 1 && null != result.get(0)) {
            list1.addAll(result.get(0).getTopProducts());
            mAdapterPopularGoods.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mRecyclerViewPopularGoods.setLayoutAnimation(layoutAnimationController);

        }

        if (result.size() >= 2 && null != result.get(1)) {
            list2.addAll(result.get(1).getTopProducts());
            mAdapterPopularGoods2.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mRecyclerViewPopularGoods.setLayoutAnimation(layoutAnimationController);
        }

        if (result.size() >= 3 && null != result.get(2)) {
            list3.addAll(result.get(2).getTopProducts());
            mAdapterPopularGoods3.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mRecyclerViewStationeryGoods.setLayoutAnimation(layoutAnimationController);
        }

    }




}



@Override
public void stopProgress() {
    getLoadingDialog().hideDialog();
}



@Override
public void onProductClicked(Product product) {
    mNavigator.toProductActivity(getContext(),product);
 }
  }
```

Is there any mistake?

Comment: why use ScrollView inside a RecyclerView.RecyclerView is way better options as compared toscrollview

Comment: use the nested recyclerview concept when there are more recyclerviews @Mr Java

Comment: @Venky There I have another views inside scrollView so that I cant user RecyclerView as Root layout.For understanding xml I cut them

Comment: Mr @Brahma Datta I tried to use NestedScrollView but it doesn't help

Comment: what is your device android version?

Comment: @mohammadReza Abiri android 9

Comment: @MrJava try to add `setNestedScrollingEnabled = false` in every recyclerview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I achieved.I used NestedScrollView as root.And used only 1 recyclerview.And in adapter of this recyclerview I created other recyclerViews.Scrolling smooth Thanks @Venky

Answer (score 0):

Try the following -

1. Try to put all the views inside NestedScrollView i.e, root view.
2. Set recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false); for both the recyclerViews in your xml.

Answer (score 0):

Change your recycler view's `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` and then use Nested scrollView with `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);`

Answer (score 0):

try to change your `ScrollView` with `NestedScrollView`and Change your recycler view's `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".fragments.MainFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:textColor="@color/blacker"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="Техника для офиса"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView_popular_goods"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:textColor="@color/blacker"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="Компьютерная техника"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView_competitive_goods"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:textColor="@color/blacker"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="Канцелярские товары"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView_stationery_goods"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

and :

```
RecyclerView recycleView1 = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_popular_goods);
RecyclerView recycleView2 = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_competitive_goods);
RecyclerView recycleView3 = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_stationery_goods);

recycleView1.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
recycleView2.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
recycleView3.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

If your devices API is below v 21, use the following:

```
ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(recycleView1, false);
ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(recycleView2, false);
ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(recycleView3, false);
```

Comment: I tested your code With a hypothetical adapter , and recycleView1.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));  And it worked well for me! can I see your adapter and your activity?

Comment: Yes How can I paste code in comments.I am new in stackOverflow?

Comment: Do you want to use your RecyclerViews horizontally?

Comment: Yeap.I need horizontal recyclerView

Comment: Does your ScrollView or Nested Scroll only work slowly? Or your RecyclerView scroll slowly too ?

Comment: Both ScrollView and RecyclerView are slow

Comment: mohammadReza Abiri Hi.Today I noticed while loading recyclerview not slow.While starting to show images(downloads by Glide) on recyclerview then started being slow

Answer (score 0):

Your design needs to change. As soon as you're adding RecyclerView with nested scrolling  disabled, you should keep in mind that view will have its items created all at once.

It basically means no typical RecyclerView optimization magic when only needed amount of items is created and rendered, then reused, based on screen real estate etc.

In your case the situation is even less good as you have 3 such RecyclerViews. The performance of your solution will of course depend on hardware and number of items inside each RecyclerView, but pls do consider using just ONE RecyclerView and no ScrollView at all.